# Merge [passwords] and [password] tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The [password](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password) and [passwords](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passwords) tags should be merged, as they refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has now been done. All instances of [password](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password) have been changed to [passwords](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passwords)